# Thrift for cassandra insert/batch_mutate increases steadily when called in a loop

Tags: java, cassandra, thrift

I have a java app that reads data out of a partitioned Oracle table (a couple of columns actually, sizing roughly around 100G) and loads into a Cassandra cluster using a number of threads equal to the number of partitions. A thread that monitors the progress displays the progress for each thread (rows inserted @ ?? ms/rec) as under:

The problem is, whatever api method (insert/batch_mutate) I call (from inside a while loop), the latency is increasing steadily. As you can see, it starts with less than 10ms/rec and goes up steadily and consistently. Any guess as to what could be the reason?

**PS**: I chose raw thrift client over hector for some reasons, and I can't go for a higher level client unless that is the only solution available. In any case, I am curious about this strange behavior.

**Sample Output from the monitoring thread**:

```
24@0 ms/rec, 135323@485 ms/rec, 131821@513 ms/rec, 155841@339 ms/rec, 243@0 ms/rec,                              226146@538 ms/rec, 0, 0, .
24@0 ms/rec, 135431@523 ms/rec, 131939@427 ms/rec, 156008@316 ms/rec, 243@0 ms/rec, 226247@553 ms/rec, 0, 0, .
24@0 ms/rec, 135534@535 ms/rec, 132052@506 ms/rec, 156172@345 ms/rec, 243@0 ms/rec, 226355@472 ms/rec, 0, 0, .
24@0 ms/rec, 135643@519 ms/rec, 132171@455 ms/rec, 156323@387 ms/rec, 243@0 ms/rec, 226464@492 ms/rec, 0, 0, .
24@0 ms/rec, 135735@498 ms/rec, 132273@514 ms/rec, 156466@355 ms/rec, 243@0 ms/rec, 226561@508 ms/rec, 0, 0, .
24@0 ms/rec, 135858@474 ms/rec, 132404@455 ms/rec, 156630@330 ms/rec, 243@0 ms/rec, 226676@533 ms/rec, 0, 0, .
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do not you build all the inserts in the loop and try the "batch_mutate" after?
I guess that the performance will be better, and you do not need Hector to use "batch_mutate" (also available in thrift, lower level implementation).
Maybe it could be due to Hector's implementation.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.

I was not aware that batch_mutate could be used to mutate a bunch of records at a time. I'll look at the doc today. If you have a link please post it here.

Comment: Asking for too much of help, but an example code snippet would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: Hi, it worked for me (do not worry about japanese comments, it is very easy to understand): http://d.hatena.ne.jp/akishin999/20100507/1273254065